# Emulate/use Continuations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, continuations

I have a function that computes product of numbers in an array. The function should work like this

```
function prod (array){
//compute and return product
}

var arr = [1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9];

the function call:
prod(arr); //should return 6
prod(arr); //should return 20
prod(arr); //should return 336 (6*7*8)
prod(arr); //should return 9
prod(arr); //should return 0
prod(arr); //should return 0
prod(arr); //should return 0
```

In scheme, this is done with continuations, by storing previous state of the function (state of the function is captured just before its exit point) [see this](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation)

So, in short, I want the javascript function return different values at different times with same parameter passed everytime.

JavaScript is a well designed language, so I hope there must be something which can emulate this. If there happens to be nothing in JS to do it, I do not mind to conclude with failure and move on. So, feel free to say its impossible.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldnt you have a static variable keepmtrack of your state?

Comment: The product of those numbers will always be zero until you get all the zeroes out.

Comment: Not clear - how these values are returns?

Comment: it's returning the product of all numbers up to the next zero, then the next call starts at the next zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is not capable of supporting continuations: it lacks tail-calls.

Generally I would write this to use a "queue" of sorts, although CPS is also do-able (just have a finite stack :-) Note that other state can also be captured in the closure, making it an "explicit continuation" of sorts ... in a very gross sense.

Example using a closure and a queue:

```
function prodFactory (array){
   // dupe array first if needed, is mutated below.
   // function parameters are always locally scoped.
   array.unshift(undefined)  // so array.shift can be at start
   // also, perhaps more closured state
   var otherState
   // just return the real function, yippee!
   return function prod () {
      array.shift()
      // do stuff ... e.g. loop array.shift() and multiply
      // set otherState ... eat an apple or a cookie
      return stuff
   }
}

var prod = prodFactory([1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9])

        // array at "do stuff", at least until "do stuff" does more stuff
prod()  // [1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9]
prod()  // [2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9]
prod()  // [3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9]
```

Happy coding.

---

"Finished implementation". Although this particular problem can avoid array mutation and just use an index: the same concepts apply. (Well, slightly different. With just an index the closed over variable would be altered, whereas with this approach an object is mutated.)

```
function prodFactory (array) {
   array = array.slice(0)
   return function prod () {
      var p = 1
      for (var n = array.shift(); n; n = array.shift()) {
        p *= n
      }
      return p
   }
}

var prod = prodFactory([1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7,8,0,9])

prod()  // 6
prod()  // 20
prod()  // 336
```

Comment: solution looks good to me. Side note: Tail calls are not necessary for continuations to work. Rhino supported continuations--albeit at function-granularity--the last time I checked.

Comment: @JohnClements True, I was assuming with the [JavaScript] language-level and not other forms of stack manipulation ;-) That is interesting -- I didn't know any JS engines had implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the function a property that will be remembered between calls:

```
function prod (array){
   if (typeof prod.index === "undefined" || prod.currentArray != array) {
      prod.currentArray = array;
      prod.index = 0;
   }

   if (prod.index >= array.length)
      return 0;

   //compute and return product
   var p = 1,
       c;
   while (prod.index < array.length) {
      c = array[prod.index++];
      if (c === 0)
         return p;
      p *= c;
   }
   return p;
}
```

I'm just guessing from your description of what should be returned that on an individual call to the function it should take the product of all of the numbers up to but not including the next zero or the end of the array. Calls after the end of the array should return 0? I may have the algorithm wrong for that, but you get the idea for what I'm suggesting to remember the function state between calls.

I've added a property to remember the current array being processed. As long as you keep passing the same array in to the function it will continue with the next elements, but if you pass a different array it will reset...

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like

```
var index = 0;
function prod (array){
    if(index < array.length){
    var prod=1;
    for(int i=index;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] != 0){
            prod = prod * array[i];
        }
        else{
            index = i+1;
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
return 0;   
}
```

this will update the global variable index everytime the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here are [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29). As of 1.7, [JavaScript supports them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).